# Struct variable in class in heap and usage of smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, smart-pointers

How can I use smart pointer here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    char data;
    node *next;
};

class linked_list
{
private:
    node *head,*tail,*tmp;
public:
    linked_list()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    void add_node()
    {
        tmp = new node();
        cin>> tmp->data;
        tmp->next = nullptr;

        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        tmp=head;
        while(tmp!=nullptr)
        {
            cout<<tmp->data;
            tmp=tmp->next;
            cout<<endl;
        }       
    }
};
int main()
{
    linked_list a;
    a.add_node();
    a.add_node();
    a.add_node();
    a.add_node();
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change first line of code of `add_note` function to use smart pointer and not have to worry about `new`/`delete` later. What changes are required? Should I have to change multiple lines of code? If so,then where?

Comment: You don't change just that pointer; you change them all.

Comment: Could you please type the code here with changes?I'm kinda new to smart_ptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is probably the most appropriate here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct node
{
    char data;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};

class linked_list
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    node* tail;
public:
    linked_list()
    : tail( nullptr )
    {
    }

    void add_node()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<node> tmp(new node());
        std::cin >> tmp->data;

        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            head = std::move(tmp);
            tail = head.get();
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = std::move(tmp);
            tail = tail->next.get();
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        auto tmp=head.get();
        while(tmp!=nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << tmp->data;
            tmp = tmp->next.get();
            std::cout << "\n";
        }       
    }
};
int main()
{
    linked_list a;
    a.add_node();
    a.add_node();
    a.add_node();
    a.add_node();
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Some notes:

1. I've removed the `tmp` member variable, there is no good reason to have it as a member variable.
2. `tail` is a raw pointer as the nodes are owned through a chain from the `head` member
3. You could use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` but a single chain of ownership seems to make more sense for a linked list

Comment: I would use `std::make_unique` to avoid completely `new`.